# get the last 5000 entries of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

i currently have the following query

```
SELECT name, bio, original_username FROM indo_accounts_data WHERE id > 180000 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5000
```

instead of doing a random 5000, i want to query the last 5000 entries of the table.. so say the table has id 1 to 1000000, i wanted to get row 995000 till 1000000 , how do i do so in a single query ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Order desc on the auto increment key

```
SELECT name, bio, original_username FROM indo_accounts_data 
ORDER BY id desc 
LIMIT 5000
```